# How do I wait for a subprocess to finish, store it's output and add a prefix (without a new line) to the output?

Tags: python, python-3.x, io, subprocess, output

I have a Python(3) script that's calling an external command using the `subprocess.call([...])` method:

```
import subprocess

print("Prefix: ")
subprocess.call(["cmd", "--option", "filename.x"])
```

The command executes without any errors but the problem is the output.

The output isn't *"uniform"* and sometimes the program will output:

```
Program output...
Prefix:
```

And other times the output will be:

```
Prefix:
Program output....
```

The result I'm looking for is:

```
Prefix: Program output...
```

I know that in order to achieve this result I need to wait for the subprocess to finish, store it's output and then print the prefix (without `\n`) with the subprocess' output after it, I just can't figure out **how** to do it.

Thanks.

Comment: It won't work, you have to wait for the command, even if you remove the new line the command might finish **BEFORE** the prefix is printed, the program doesn't take a set/specific amount of time, see answer below.

Comment: `print('Prefix : ', end=' ', flush=True)`. It should be printed before your next instruction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to import the `sys` module, so you can use `sys.stdout`'s `write` and `flush` methods.

```
import sys
```

You'll also need to import the subprocess module so you can use the `subprocess.check_output` method.

```
import subprocess
```

Use `sys.stdout.write` instead of `print`:

```
sys.stdout.write("Prefix: ")
```

Then you'll need to replace `subprocess.call` with `subprocess.check_output`, which runs the given command and **waits** for the output.

```
response = subprocess.check_output(["cmd", "--option", "filename.x"])
```

**NOTE:** you need to decode the response because it's a bytes object and not a string.

```
sys.stdout.write(response.decode("UTF-8"))
```

And finally you need to flush the output:

```
sys.stdout.flush()
```

Here is the final result:

```
import sys, subprocess
sys.stdout.write("Prefix: ")
response = subprocess.check_output(["cmd", "--option", "filename.x"])
sys.stdout.write(response.decode("UTF-8"))
sys.stdout.flush()
```

Good luck, hopefully no one else will stumble on this question like I did.